# Как получить список директорий без поддиректорий

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловая-система

Читал - есть куча способов, типа:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(DBFolder, 'insects')):
  for f in dirs:
   logger.info(f)
```

Но все они получают списки с поддиректориями
А мне нужен только список директорий по адресу (БЕЗ поддиректорий)
Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сначала получить список всех файлов и папок, а потом просто отсеять из них папки.

Пример:

```py
import os

for something in os.listdir():
    if os.path.isdir(something):
        print(something)
```